# KeeWeb Installation Error

Tags: apt

After downloading the deb file of keeweb which is KeeWeb-1.6.3.linux.x64 i try to install using the keeweb using`sudo dpkg -i /home/kaganovich/Downloads/KeeWeb-1.6.3.linux.x64.deb` i got error in my terminal which says `dpkg: error processing package keeweb-desktop (--install):`

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit operating system?

Also please provide complete error output.

Try running `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: https://ibb.co/hCZp3o
https://ibb.co/gkgf9T

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt install -f` this should rectify your problem.

Comment: Could you expand on this at all? Describe what the command you suggest is doing please.